# An array Board(3,3) is valid, but an array Board(6,7) is not?

Tags: java, arrays, 2d-games

I have been working on an assignment that requires I code the board games: Tic-Tac-Toe, Connect 4, and Mastermind. My current headache lies in the fact that I can make a two dimensional array named Board with the parameters of (3,3) to define the tic tac toe 9 celled game board, BUT i can not make an array named Board with the parameters of (6,7) to define the Connect 4 board, or even (5,8) for Mastermind. Is there a rule I'm totally over looking?

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6
        at games.board.Board.<init>(Board.java:10)
        at BoardGameTester.main(BoardGameTester.java:15)
    Java Result: 1
```

Source for main(): http://pastebin.com/CA7Ecp8H
Source for Board.java: http://pastebin.com/PjqHfap4

Also, I am not asking for an answer to the project, I am merely asking for more info as to why I am unable to make a non squared array.

Comment: you should post the relevant parts of your source code here

Comment: SSCCE not possible, and main post includes paste bin of main and board source code.

Comment: Can you verify that your pastes are accurate? The stack trace suggests that there is an error in your constructor at line 16, but according to your source, line 16 is a different method entirely.

Comment: recompiled, for some reason I lost 7 lines some how.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was an ugly typo for the given source code. The correct code which was supplied by my instructor:

```
public Board(int rows, int columns) {
    cells = new Cell[rows][columns];
    for( int r = 0; r < cells.length; r++) {
        for( int c = 0; c < cells[r].length; c++) {
            cells[r][c] = new Cell(r,c);
        }
    }
}
```